# Clash Between Multiple Locales in a mod_perl Setting?

Tags: perl, internationalization, mod-perl, mason

I'm currently working on internationalizing a large Perl/Mason web application (Perl 5.8.0, Mason 1.48, mod_perl & Apache). In choosing a localization module, I decided to go with [Locale::TextDomain](http://search.cpan.org/~guido/libintl-perl-1.20/lib/Locale/TextDomain.pm#SYNOPSIS) over Locale::Maketext, mostly because the latter's plural form support isn't as nice as I'd like.

The hang-up I'm having with Locale::TextDomain is that it resolves which catalog to use for translations based on the process' locale. When I realized this, I got worried about how this would affect my application if I wanted users to be able to use different locales -- would it be possible that a change in locale to suit one user's settings would affect another user's session? For example, could there be a situation in which an English user received a page in German because a German user's session changed the process' locale? I'm not very knowledgeable about how Apache's thread/process model works, though it seems that if multiple users can be served by the same thread, this could happen.

[This email thread](http://osdir.com/ml/web.mason.user/2003-02/msg00038.html) would indicate that this is possible; [here](http://osdir.com/ml/web.mason.user/2003-02/msg00042.html) the OP describes the situation I'm thinking about.

If this is true, is there a way I can prevent this scenario while still using Locale::TextDomain? I suppose I could always hack at the module to load the catalogs in a locale-independent (probably using DBD::PO), but hopefully I'm just missing something that will solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

<s>You entirely avoid the `setlocale` problems by using [`web_set_locale`](http://p3rl.org/Locale%3a%3aUtil#web_set_locale-ACCEPT_LANGUAGE-ACCEPT_CHARSET-CATEGORY-AVAILABLE-) instead.</s>

(That message on the mailing list predates the addition of that function by about 4 years.)

---

<s>Edit: You are correct that global behaviour persists in Apache children, leading to [buggy behaviour](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/porting.html#Sometimes_it_Works__Sometimes_it_Doesn_t).</s>

I wrote up a test case:

**app.psgi**

```
use 5.010;
use strictures;
use Foo::Bar qw(run);

my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    run($env);
};
```

**Foo/Bar.pm**

```
package Foo::Bar;
use 5.010;
use strictures;
use Encode qw(encode);
use File::Basename qw(basename);
use Locale::TextDomain __PACKAGE__, '/tmp/Foo-Bar/share/locale';
use Locale::Util qw(web_set_locale);
use Plack::Request qw();
use Sub::Exporter -setup => { exports => [ 'run' ] };

our $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'; # untranslated source strings

sub run {
    my ($env) = @_;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    web_set_locale($env->{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}, undef, undef, [
        map { basename $_ } grep { -d } glob '/tmp/Foo-Bar/share/locale/*'
    ]); # XXX here
    return $req
        ->new_response(
            200, 
            ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'],
            [encode('UTF-8', __ 'Hello, world!')],
        )->finalize;
}
```

The app runs as a PerlResponseHandler. When the user request a language that cannot be set, the call fails silently and the language that was used last successfully is still enabled.

The trick to fix this is to always set to a language that exists with a fallback mechanism. At the spot marked XXX, add the code `or web_set_locale($DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)`, so that despite using a global setting, the behaviour cannot persist because we guarantee that it is set/changed once per request.

---

Edit 2: Further testing reveals that it's not thread-safe, sorry. Use the `prefork` MPM only which isolates requests as processes; however `worker` and `event` are affected because they are thread-based.

Comment: Is there documentation than the CPAN page that says web_set_locale is thread safe? According to the documentation at that link, web_set_locale calls Locale::Util::set_locale, whose documentation specifies that it uses POSIX::setlocale -- my impression is that web_set_locale does not actually solve this problem, but I may be missing something important.